# Type does not contain method when using default queue

Tags: c#, redis, job-scheduling, hangfire

I am trying to enqueue or schedule jobs (e.g. sending mails). Here is what I observed during trial/error process:

- In development and production environments, we are using same redis server. Redis configurations are same and both sides are using only one queue: `default`. So when other developers are debugging the code, they become servers that are listening default queue.
- When I try to enqueue or schedule a job I recently developed on my machine and debug it, it is not executed, it is seen in 'Retries' section. Method is simply not found. After 10 retries, it fails. (By the way, I am using `Enqueue<T>` and `Schedule<T>` methods.)
- When I introduce a new queue (e.g. test) in Startup.cs, and enqueue the new job with `BackgroundJobClient` and specify queue name with `EnqueuedState("test")`, it is executed immediately.

I didn't get the relationship between jobs (functions) and queues after all these. Can someone explain me why my jobs fail when they are executed in "default" queue, and why they are successful when they are executed in different queue?

Also, can someone explain me why I face "the method is not found" problem when I try to run a job?

I am asking these questions, since I want to learn real reason behind all these issues, rather than making inferences.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will answer,but i had the same problem and found out a few things

- queue names arent supported when you use `Schedule` (or Recurring Jobs),only when you directly `Enqueue` them (unless you custom create a system to support it).[See this](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/specify-hangfire-queue-in-backgroundjob-calling-method/500/3),it's old but should still be valid.
- if you have multiple services running hangfire to manage different kinds of jobs,be sure to give each of them a different hangfire database to store their data.If you place them all on the same database,when a job needs to start HF will search for a default queue to run it (unless you specify the queue name but..see above).
- But each service will have an HF server with a default queue and no indication of which one is the correct one...So HF might end trying to run it on the server of another service,that wont have any idea of what the job is calling since it's not linked to the correct code base [(again,see this)](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VpcEPfRCGL4J:https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/910+&cd=1&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it&client=firefox-b-ab).
  On the other hand,if you specify the name of the queue ,and that name's only on the server 'linked' to the correct code, HF will run the job on that queue (again,as long as you are not scheduling it) , find what it needs, and everything will work

Hope this can help a bit